# Basis provided by Ns() in R Epi package

Tags: r, spline

As I was working out how [Epi](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Epi/index.html) generates the basis for its spline functions (via the function `Ns`), I was a little confused by how it handles the `detrend` argument.

When `detrend=T` I would have expected that `Epi::Ns(...)` would more or less project the basis given by `splines::ns(...)` onto the orthogonal complement of the column space of `[1 t]` and finally extract the set of linearly independent columns (so that we have a basis).

However, this doesn’t appear to be the *exactly* the case; I tried

```
library(Epi)
x=seq(-0.75, 0.75, length.out=5)
Ns(x, knots=c(-0.5,0,0.5), Boundary.knots=c(-1,1), detrend=T)
```

and

```
library(splines)
detrend(ns(x, knots=c(-0.5,0,0.5), Boundary.knots=c(-1,1)), x)
```

The matrices produced by the above code are not the same, however, they do have the same column space (in this example) suggesting that if plugged in to a linear model, the fitted coefficients will be different but the fit (itself) will be the same.

The first question I had was; is this true in general?

The second question is why are the two different?

Regarding the second question - when `detrend` is specified, `Epi::Ns` gives a warning that `fixsl` is ignored.

Diving into Epi github [NS.r](https://github.com/cran/Epi/blob/master/R/Ns.r) ... in the construction of the basis, in the call to `Epi::Ns` above with `detrend=T`, the worker `ns.ld()` is called (a function almost identical to the guts of `splines::ns()`), which passes `c(NA,NA)` along to `splines::spline.des` as the `derivs` argument in determining a matrix `const`;

```
const <- splines::spline.des( Aknots, Boundary.knots, 4, c(2-fixsl[1],2-fixsl[2]))$design
```

This is the difference between what happens in `Ns(detrend=T)` and the call to `ns()` above which passes `c(2,2)` to splineDesign as the `derivs` argument.

So that explains how they are different, but not *why*? Does anyone have an explanation for why `fixsl=c(NA,NA)` is used instead of `fixsl=c(F,F)` in `Epi::Ns()`?

And does anyone have a proof/or an answer to the first question? 
I think the orthogonal complement of `const`'s column space is used so that second (or desired) derivatives are zero at the boundary (via projection of the general spline basis) - but *I'm not sure about this step as I haven't dug into the mathematics, I'm just going by my 'feel' for it*. Perhaps if I understood this better, the reason that the differences in the result for `const` from the call to `splineDesign`/`spline.des` (in `ns()` and `Ns()` respectively) would explain why the two matrices from the start are not the same, yet yield the same fit.

Comment: I suspect that the person best able to answer this will be the package maintainer.  You can find them using `maintainer('Epi')`.

Comment: Sadly; even with a 'Dr' title, it is hard to get responses from academics unless you are offering to write a paper for them :|

Comment: It's unclear whether you made a good faith effort to follow dww's suggestion. I haven't always agreed with Bendix Carstensen, but he has always seemed to be supportive towards users wrestling with his packages. If you did make some effort, then maybe your communication style needs some adjustment?

Comment: I will back up both dww and 42 on this. I have written to MANY package maintainers/authors with overwhelmingly positive results. If you have not, and still want to know this answer, you should!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fixsl=c(NA,NA)` was a bug that has been fixed since a while. See the commits on the CRAN Github mirror.

I have still sent an email to the maintainer to ask if the fix could be made a little bit more consistent with the condition, but in principle this could be closed.

Comment: Looks like the code was updated less than a week after I first posted this; having already posted about it on the mailing list in April 2017. As I never got a reply I guess I missed the bug-fix. I can confirm that the two calls that i thought should be equivalent now produce the same matrix.